# Fuzzy floating point checks against mock call argumnets in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Given a function with a signature

```
interface Position {
  x: number, y: number
}

function f(position: Position): void { … }
```

I want to mock it in a test

```
// given
const f = jest.fn()

// when
// exercise SUT

// then
expect(f).toHaveBeenCalledWith<Position>({x: 1.0, y: 1.0});
```

But unfortunately, I'm dealing with floating points, so I need the check to allow for some leeway. Now, I *could* do

```
expect(f.mock.calls[0][0].x).toBeCloseTo(1, 1);
expect(f.mock.calls[0][0].y).toBeCloseTo(1, 1);
```

But that gets old *real* fast. There's a ticket that the Jest maintainers [don't seem to think warrants inclusion in Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3654) and a package to [match using `expect`](https://github.com/maasencioh/jest-matcher-deep-close-to) but it doesn't do what I'd like to do! Which something like:

```
expect(f).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining({
    x: expect.numberCloseTo(1), 
    y: expect.numberCloseTo(1)
   });
```

Is there something like that or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: No, there's no builtin but you can add your own with `expect.extend`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aleksey already hinted at, I needed to write my own custom matcher. So, here it goes:

```
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Expect {
      numberCloseTo(expected: number, precision?: number): any;
    }
  }
}

expect.extend({
  numberCloseTo(actual: number, expected: number, precision: number = 2) {
    expect(actual).toBeCloseTo(expected, precision);
    return { message: () => "This shouldn't happen.", pass: true };
  },
});
```

And here's how I use it:

```
expect(f).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining<Position>({
    x: expect.numberCloseTo(1, 1),
    y: expect.numberCloseTo(1, 1),
  })
);
```

Extending already existing matchers is super-awkward in Jest, and I guess [that's by design](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3139). So we need to include a dummy message.

The TS only `declare global` etc. can be dropped if you're using Flow or plain JS.